# How to expand efficiently daterange pandas dataframe with groups

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby, processing-efficiency

I have a large dataset with multiple groups that contains two columns of start and end dates and column of a value (each group can have multiple values)
I want to expand it efficiently and get a new dataframe which have time (in seconds) as index and column for each group that will store the value in it

The data looks like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['start'] = [dt.datetime(2017, 4, 3,5,22,21), dt.datetime(2017, 4, 5,3,51,22),\
               dt.datetime(2017, 4, 4,4,23,33),dt.datetime(2017, 4, 3,7,28,45),\
               dt.datetime(2017, 4, 6,5,22,24),dt.datetime(2017, 4, 6,5,22,56)]

df['end'] = [dt.datetime(2017, 4, 3,6,33,23), dt.datetime(2017, 4,5,3,52,46),\
             dt.datetime(2017, 4,4,4,58,12),dt.datetime(2017, 4, 4,1,23,34),\
            dt.datetime(2017, 4, 7,5,22,24),dt.datetime(2017, 4, 7,5,22,47)]
df['group'] = ['1', '2', '3','1','2','3']
df['value'] = ['a', 'b', 'c','b','c','a']

start   end group   value
0   2017-04-03 05:22:21 2017-04-03 06:33:23 1   a
1   2017-04-05 03:51:22 2017-04-05 03:52:46 2   b
2   2017-04-04 04:23:33 2017-04-04 04:58:12 3   c
3   2017-04-03 07:28:45 2017-04-04 01:23:34 1   b
4   2017-04-06 05:22:24 2017-04-03 05:22:24 2   c
5   2017-04-03 05:22:56 2017-04-03 05:22:47 3   a
```

I tried the following method:

1. Constructing a new dataframe with index in a range of the earliest start and the latest end.
2. Grouping by the group_ID
3. Iterating over the group rows, creating from each row a small dataframe with index in the row's start date and row's end date storing the row's value

4.Concatenating the small dataframes from the same group into one dataframe

5. Joining (left join) the group dataframe ( which is in fact a column of values on dates index ) to the big dataframe (adding it as a column )

Here is the snippet:

```py
def turn_deltas(row,col):
    key = str(row['group'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(row['start'], row['end'], freq="1S"))
    df[key] = row[col]
    return df

grouped = df.groupby("group")
data = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(df['start'].min(), df['end'].max(), freq="1s")) 
for name, group in (grouped):
    for i, row in enumerate(group.iterrows()):
        if i == 0:
            df_2 = turn_deltas(row[1],"value")
        else:
            df_2 = pd.concat([df_2, turn_deltas(row[1],"value")], axis=0)
    data = data.merge(df_2, how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)

print (data)
```

My code is working but do the task very (very) slow

Finally, I got this updated dataframe:

```
2017-04-03 05:22:21    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:22    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:23    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:24    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:25    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:26    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:27    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:28    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:29    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:30    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:31    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:32    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:33    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:34    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:35    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:36    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:37    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:38    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:39    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:40    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:41    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:42    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:43    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:44    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:45    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:46    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:47    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:48    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:49    a  NaN  NaN
2017-04-03 05:22:50    a  NaN  NaN
...                  ...  ...  ...
2017-04-07 05:22:18  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:19  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:20  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:21  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:22  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:23  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:24  NaN    c    a
2017-04-07 05:22:25  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:26  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:27  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:28  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:29  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:30  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:31  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:32  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:33  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:34  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:35  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:36  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:37  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:38  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:39  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:40  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:41  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:42  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:43  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:44  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:45  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:46  NaN  NaN    a
2017-04-07 05:22:47  NaN  NaN    a
```

**Note**:
This code is just a part from the whole project.
After I perform this transformation I also use `get_dummies()` in order to get a separate column for each value of each column so you might take it into your implementation strategy as well

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `merge_ordered` to build a dataframe per group indexed by the index of your `data` dataframe. It will have unwanted values, so they should be cleaned. But from then, it is easy to build your final dataframe:

```
for g, dg in df.groupby('group'):
    # build a dataframe per group with the final index
    dy = pd.merge_ordered(data.rename_axis('dat').reset_index(), dg,
         left_on='dat', right_on='start', fill_method='ffill')
    # clean values outside of [start:end] range
    dy.loc[(dy.start>dy.dat)|(dy.dat>dy.end), 'group'] = np.nan
    dy.loc[(dy.start>dy.dat)|(dy.dat>dy.end), 'value'] = np.nan
    # and use that to set the column in the final dataframe
    data[g] = dy.set_index('dat').value
```

If performance really matters, proper index usage makes a difference. This version should be about 3 times faster:

```
for g, dg in df.groupby('group'):
    # build a dataframe per group with the final index
    dy = pd.merge_asof(data, dg.set_index('start'),
                 left_index=True, right_index=True)
    # clean values outside of [start:end] range
    dy.loc[dy.index>dy.end,'value'] = np.nan
    # and use that to set the column in the final dataframe
    data[g] = dy.value
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. two things I have noticed:
1. I ran your code but the result is quite different from the desired one - at the end you will see that in your result each column has some value but it's not suppose to happen (e.g column 1 has 'b' value at 07-04-2017 but the last event ended in the 04-04-17

Comment: @AviEini: I had a typo in the `dy.loc[..., 'value'] = np.nan` line: I wrote a `&` when it should be `|`. I have edited my post and hope results should be better now...

Comment: Thanks for your correction. works great!
2. About the efficiency. I tried it with my Jupyter notebook and use %%timeit to examine the differences - my code time takes 203ms and yours takes 880ms.
I would be glad if you can have another look.
thanks!

Comment: @AviEini: I could slightly improve my version, which should give same performances as yours on a tiny dataframe. For larger ones, my versions should be faster because they do not require any `iterrows` and are fully vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really convert the value to some dtype other than object i.e use 0,1,2 instead of 'a','b','c'.

As for the conversion code, this seems really fast, at least on your sample df. and pretty short and readable as well.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(df['start'].min(), df['end'].max(), freq="1S"))

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    data.loc[(data.index >= row['start'])&(data.index<=row['end']),
             row['group']] = row['value']
```